# Plotting a piecewise function MRI problem

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I have this M.R.I. question, and i need to plot a function with some 'a' and 'b' parameters and 't' as a variable:

```
M[a_, b_, t_] := Piecewise[{
                  {Exp[-t/(1/a + 1/b)],             0 < t < 15},
                  {Exp[-t/a]*Exp[-(30 - t)/b],     15 < t < 30},
                  {Exp[-t/(1/a  + 1/b)]*Exp[30/b],      t > 30}
                 }]
```

I tried using:

```
Plot[M[100, 100, x], {x, 0, 50}]
```

But it does not work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Don't just say "does not work". Be specific. "This is what I expected (why?), and this is what happened instead." Also, I don't know what MRI means, other than Magnetic Resonance Imaging.

Comment: It seems to work just fine in that a plot is obtained. Whether this is the plot you want, that's  a completely different story, I am afraid. Try adding `PlotStyle -> Red` to your `Plot` expression to make the lines more visible, and perhaps changing the values of the parameters to `M` to see their effects.

Comment: Look at `M[100, 100, x]//Simplify`and `Plot[M[100, 100, x], {x, 0, 0.25}, MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: `mnew=FullSimplify[Log[M[100, 100, x]], Assumptions -> x > 0];Plot[mnew,{x,0,50}]` Works?